# Using Ajax to Trigger Query To Update Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax, database

I have a dynamic HTML table that can be edited in multiple ways. There is an edit button where you can edit inline, the information of the rows and then click save to save the information. A deactivate button that grays out the row and an activate button that appears afterwards in order to reactivate it. And also and add row button that brings up a dialog box where you can hit add row again and add another row to the table.

However, while that is all nice...I want to write these changes/updates to a SQL Server database now so it actually saves them. I want to be able to automatically save these changes after each action (save, deactivate/activate, and add row) happens. I want an UPDATE query for when the Save button is clicked and an INSERT query to run after the Add Row button in the form is clicked. I have some Ajax now but it doesn't work. I have all the necessary code to focus on the add row button writing to the DB for now. I have never done anything like this before so any help/advice/code would be appreciated!

HTML/PHP code:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">

</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript and ajax for dialog box:

```
// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );

      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val() );
        });
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );





$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var mr_name = $("#mr_name").val();
var buyer_id = $("#buyer_id").val();
var poc_n = $("#poc_n").val();
var poc_e = $("#poc_e").val();
var poc_p = $("#poc_p").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'mr_name1='+ mr_name + '&buyer_id1='+ buyer_id + '&poc_n1='+ poc_n + '&poc_e1='+ poc_e + '&poc_p1='+ poc_p;
if(mr_name==''||buyer_id==''||poc_n==''||poc_e==''||poc_p=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Ajax Submit code:

```
<?php

$host="xxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
// Establishing Connection with Server..

//Fetching Values from URL
$mr_name2=$_POST['mr_name1'];
$buyer_id2=$_POST['buyer_id1'];
$poc_n2=$_POST['poc_n1'];
$poc_e2=$_POST['poc_e1'];
$poc_p2=$_POST['poc_p1'];

//Insert query
$query = pdo_query("INSERT into Stage_Rebate_Master(mr_name, buyer_id, poc_n, poc_e, poc_p) values ('$mr_name2', '$buyer_id2', '$poc_n2','$poc_e2', '$poc_p2')");
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
pdo_close($dbh); // Connection Closed

?>
```

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly "doesnt work"? Your html? Your query? Your php code? The ajax request? The response? Try to as more specific question.

Comment: The query/ajax/response doesn't work...I haven't worked with this before, so  I don't know how to really do much of it...like the sending a request, running the query, etc

Comment: Open the developers tool bar, check the network tab to see what is the request you send to the server, what is the response, maybe your php code has errors, etc...

Comment: its not that the php code has errors...i just don't really have an idea of how to do the ajax and sending the request to the DB to update it...while i do have some ajax code here, i am pretty sure that it is not correct....but i know my php is ifne

Comment: Your PHP code has only `insert`, while you said you want `update` so I'm almost sure your php code is not so fine..

Comment: i just need to know how to write the ajax request and then the correct code that actually does the inserting and updating

Comment: So you are looking for ajax tutorial?

Comment: That query is for the add row...which would insert a new row into the DB...so that line would be correct...i just need to be able to write the correct ajax functions and then I can write the queries myself

Comment: I suppose thats part of it...ive already looked online on google, w3schools, etc...and its not something that I am able to pick up right away just reading over it when I am needing to finish this up...i can understand the very basics of it but not nearly enough to do this